# Gemeindeverordnung interpretation

Tags: translation

I have a question about a Gemeindeverordnung. My German is good enough to read what is written here, but I'm not sure how I should interpret it. It's ambiguous to me.

[image: First paragraph is important here]

*Figure: First article is important here*

So should I interpret this as: You may not place any camping gear at places generally accessible from public roads, except at a camping site.

Or should I interpret this as: You may never place camping gear, except at camping places (with a permit, i.e. camping-organisation) accessible from public roads.

EDIT:

if you reason a contrario, you could say that, with the first interpretation, that you may place camping gear at places not generally accessible from public roads. I.e. wilderness. Is this a valid argument I could make?

Comment: What is the difference between your two interpretations? I did not see it?

Comment: Within the city limits of Wengen, tents, trailers. mobile homes etc. must not be set up for the purpose of sleeping over night in publicly accessible places. This does not apply to licensed camp sites.

Comment: IQV, if you reason a contrario, you could say that, with the first interpretation, that you may place camping gear at places not generally accessible from public roads. I.e. wilderness.

Comment: @user3351731 It does not say anything about places accessible from public roads. It only refers to places accessible by the public. Basically: No camping outside official camping sites.

Comment: You're right Roland. I suppose I meant 'Orten'. The mentioning of 'Allgemein zuganglichen' makes me think it's allowed at places not generally accessible.

Comment: Yes, you can camp in your own backyard. Wilderness is accessible (in the legal sense) to the public.

Comment: @user3351731 Can you please improve your question according to the first comment of IQV. It is really hard to understand you are aiming to the relation of camping places and public roads.

Comment: @Roland I don't think it is legal or common sense what a accessible place is and what not, in this the paragraph is really bad and could be ambiguous interpreted. But I think this is not what the OP meant.

Comment: The basic thought of this *Gemeindeordnung* is people may not camp in the forest or alp, even if it's property of some farmer. Caveat: As soon there is a fence around the area, it's not *öffentlich (allgemein zugänglich)* anymore and the property owner can allow camping. But fencing may be forbidden by another article of the *Gemeindeordnung*.

Comment: @Thomas You are mistaken. "öffentlich" and "allgemein zugänglich" are legal terms.

Comment: @Roland I agree "Öffentlich" is clear but I was in doubt for "Allgemein zugänglich", but if you say it is interchangeable I trust you, thanks.

Comment: I think a big misunderstanding comes from the idea *öffentlich* means *accessible from public roads*. That's an anglo-saxon definition. In Germany and Austria, *öffentlich* means there is no obstacle to overcome. A non-fenced field or meadow is *öffentlich* even if it isn't public property. You may even pass it freely if you don't damage the crops or startle cattle. It becomes *nicht-öffentlich* as soon there is a fence. You may never pass fences or gates (even open gates) without permission of the owner. Though the permission may be implicit, e.g. a sign at a gate, telling you *Hütte, 3km*.

Comment: Janka my dutch made it read gemeindeVERordnung. My bad. Could you back your statement "The basic thought of this Gemeindeordnung is people may not camp in the forest or alp, even if it's property of some farmer", because I really can't think of a way to extract that from the article.

Comment: It's a situation which is pretty common in mountain regions of Germany and Austria. There's a *Gemeindeordnung* which forbids fencing for the sake of tourism and at the same time it forbids camping in *allgemein zugänglichen* areals. That effectively forbids farmers to use their land as a camping site. I had to look up press articles about some court trial a few years ago which a local farmer fought against his *Gemeinde*. He wanted to fence, so he's allowed to start a camping business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this regulation has nothing to do with accessibility of areas by a public or private road.

This regulation basically forbids camping in all places but official camping sites. And the term *allgemein zugängliche Orte* is the decisive term which defines what counts as public (*öffentlich*) because e.g. forests are often owned by private persons or companies (and not by the municipality or state) however they are not fenced and everyone can enter them without restrictions. Still you are not allowed to put up your tent in such forests according to this regulation.

A term you may often come across in this context is [Wildcampen](https://www.bergfreunde.de/basislager/hotel-europa-wo-ist-wildcampen-wie-erlaubt/).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you *can* actually interpret some ambiguity into the sentence:

> ... an im Freien gelegenen öffentlichen Orten ...

could grammatically belong to the camp sites

> Campingplätze, die an im Freien gelegenen öffentlichen Orten liegen

or it could stand alone as a refinement of the predicate:

> Wohnwagen dürfen nicht an im Freien gelegenen öffentlichen Orten aufgestellt werden.

From the context, however, it is quite clear that the first interpretation doesn't make a lot of sense (Why should it be interdicted to put tents and caravans onto camping sites? That's what they're good for, after all.)

Comment: I can't see any ambiguity in *Außerhalb von Campingplatzen an im Freien gelegenen Orten*. It is all outdoor places **outside of a camp site**.